# Echo the count for each result

Tags: php

This PHP/MySQL gets the top tweeters from my database:

```
$toptweeters = mysql_query("SELECT count(user) a,user from fotetweets group by user order by a desc limit 10");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($toptweeters)) {
            echo "<li style='border: 0; margin-left: 5px;'><a target='_blank' style='border: 0;' href='http://twitter.com/".$row["user"]."'>";
            echo $row["user"];
            echo "</a></li>";
    }
```

How can I also display the count result for each of the users returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
echo $row["user"];
```

Write insetad::

```
echo $row["user"] . ": " . $row["a"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$toptweeters = mysql_query("SELECT count(user) AS `a`, `user`  FROM `fotetweets` GROUP BY `user` ORDER BY `a` DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($toptweeters)) {
        echo "<li style='border: 0; margin-left: 5px;'><a target='_blank' style='border: 0;' href='http://twitter.com/".$row["user"]."'>";
        echo $row["user"];
        echo $row["a"];
        echo "</a></li>";
    }
```